# How can I bulk-upload PDF attachments to custom objects then attach those PDFs to a mass email campaign?

Tags: email, attachment

I work at a company that runs summer programs. One of our vendors is sending us approximately 1,000 student grade reports as PDFs. The files will all be named consistently (i.e. John Doe Grade Report.pdf). There is only one file per student. We have a custom student object in our Salesforce implementation with various other data tracked. My question has two parts:

1) Can we bulk-upload these PDFs to Salesforce and associate them with the particular student record? For example, can **John Doe Grade Report.pdf** get attached to John Doe's record, **Jane Doe Grade Report.pdf** get attached to Jane Doe's record, etc.

2) Can we write a mass-email that pulls in these reports as an attachment. It would look something like this, ideally:

> Dear {Name Merge Field},
>
> Your grades are attached. Thank you.
>
> Attachment ***Name* Grade Report.pdf**

The attachment would pull the PDF attachment from the particular field we make in the custom student object.

Is there any way to (somewhat) easily do this? We're not opposed to diving into Apex code a bit if needed or pull in an App Exchange app if this isn't possible in Salesforce alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Can we bulk-upload these PDFs to Salesforce and associate them with the particular student record? For example, can John Doe Grade Report.pdf get attached to John Doe's record, Jane Doe Grade Report.pdf get attached to Jane Doe's record, etc.

YES - You can use Data Loader to upload attachments to Salesforce. Before uploading attachments, note the following:

If you intend to upload via the Bulk API, verify that Upload Bulk API Batch as Zip File on the Settings | Settings page is enabled.

**To upload attachments:**
Confirm that the CSV file you intend to use for attachment importing contains the following required columns (each column represents a Salesforce field):
1. ParentId - the Salesforce ID of the parent record. This will be Salesforce ID of a Student Record.
2. Name - the name of the attachment file, such as testPDF.pdf.
3. Body - the absolute path to the attachment on your local drive.
Ensure that the values in the Body column contain the full file name of the attachments as they exist on your computer. For example, if an attachment named testPDF.pdf is located on your computer at C:\Export, Body must specify C:\Export\testPDF.pdf.

2) Can we write a mass-email that pulls in these reports as an attachment. It would look something like this, ideally:

YES- This will involve a apex code.

1. If you want to send an email to a Student when attachment is
   inserted into SFDC then you need to write a trigger code. [Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)
   code can contain a logic to send an email to Student Record.
2. The another possible solution will be to write a [Batch apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) class,
   which will run on a daily basis. It will identify all the
   attachments which are uploaded on that day, It will find out the
   associated students and send email to those student records along
   with their PDF as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

To address your questions:

**1. Bulk-uploading PDFs to Salesforce and associating them with specific records:**

Yes, you can achieve this by using Salesforce's Data Loader or Data
Import Wizard to bulk upload the PDF files and associate them with
the respective student records. You'll need a unique identifier in
your PDF filenames that matches with a field in your custom student
object (e.g., student name, student ID). This unique identifier will
be used to map the PDFs to the correct student records during the
upload process.

You can utilize the Mass File Upload AppExchange
application to streamline the bulk upload process of PDFs and
associate them with the corresponding student records in Salesforce.
This application simplifies the task, saving time and ensuring data
accuracy. You can learn more about it, including a demo video and
test drive, at
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=82cf236b-1ee8-4ea7-aebf-fd0c89fb93bd

**2. Sending mass emails with attached PDFs from Salesforce:**

You can accomplish this by creating a custom email template in
Salesforce that includes merge fields for the student's name and the
attachment field containing the PDF. Then, you can use Salesforce's
Mass Email feature to send emails to your recipients. However,
Salesforce's native Mass Email feature does not support attaching
files directly from object records.

To attach PDFs dynamically from
the custom student object, you may need to write custom Apex code.
One possible approach could involve creating a Visualforce email
template with custom controller logic to retrieve the PDF
attachments from the student records and attach them to the outgoing
emails. Alternatively, you could explore integration with an
external document management system that allows you to link files to
Salesforce records and then include download links in your mass
emails.

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Mass File Download ad Mass File Upload AppExchange App.

Thanks,
Nikita